# HTML/CSS: The div placement changes when filled with conent

Tags: html, css

When there is no content in `<div #id="profile-body"></div>` the divs are parallel thanks to `display: inline-block;`, but when I fill this div with any kind of content, the height of the content acts as though it's changing the other divs `margin-top` that are parallel.

stylesheet.css

```
.profile-header{
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
    font-size: 1em;
    display: block;   
}

.profile-body{
    margin-left: 2%;
}

#profile-left{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30%;
    height:100%;
    min-height:300px;
}

#profile-middle{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30%;
    height:100%;
    min-height:300px;
}
#profile-middle-body div{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30%;
}
#profile-middle-body p{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 65%;
}

#profile-right{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30%;
    height:100%;
    min-height:300px;
}
```

index.html

```
<div id="profile-left">
    <div class="profile-header">
        <hr><p>Too Excessive</p><hr>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="profile-middle">
    <div class="profile-header">
        <hr><p>Bio</p><hr>
    </div>
    <div id="profile-middle-body">
        <!-- Comment to fix dix placement -->
        <div>name</div><p>Brandon Nadeau</p>
        <div>age</div><p>17</p>
        <div>location</div><p>Alaska</p>
        <div>member for</div><p>1 year</p>
        <div>profile views</div><p>62</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="profile-right">
    <div class="profile-header">
        <hr><p>About Me</p><hr>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `float` to those 3 divs. It should go up and remain there.

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZMZqb/)

```
#profile-right{
   
    width: 30%;
    height:100%;
    min-height:300px;
    float:left;
}

#profile-left{
   
    width: 30%;
    height:100%;
    min-height:300px;
    float:left;
}

#profile-middle{
   
    width: 30%;
    height:100%;
    min-height:300px;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought `float: left;` on all of them would make them overlap.

Comment: Not really they wont overlap, they will just appear side by side based on the order in which they are placed...

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using inline-block with % widths for the layout - if you want to avoid floats, you could also try vertical-align:top; on all 3 divs.

Comment: Thanks, using vertical-align is a little less confusing